# Input printed again when using std::cin

Tags: c++, cin

I've tried googling for this, but was unable to find an answer.

Sometimes, when I'm using `std::cin`, whatever I input is being printed again to the console after hitting Enter. It might be limited to my machine/compiler but I'm completely clueless as to why this happens, and why it happens only occasionally.

This is some example code:

```
int n;
std::cout << "Enter n:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> n;
```

Which outputs (if I input, say, 3)

```
Enter n:
3
3
```

But only the 3 that is on the line after the `Enter n:` is the one I input. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Edit: As this *could* be an IDE issue, I'm using CLion 2018.1.3

Comment: OS? Terminal emulator? Compiler and standard library implementation?

Comment: Windows 10, I'm not using any emulators, Compiler is MingW 32 or 64 bit, and libstdc++, using C++11

Comment: It can never be on the same line, as the stream will have been flushed with `std::endl`.

Comment: Following your edit, the terminal emulation in CLion and other JetBrains tools is not the greatest.

Comment: @NeilButterworth You're right about the `std::endl` bit, I forgot I added that in here. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it's a Clion issue. Run your program in CMD or Powershell to see it

Comment: @ThomasSablik You're correct. I should have thought about running it directly earlier.

Comment: I am using CLion too, but I don't have this issue.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `’\n’` ends a line. Further, `std::cout` and `std::cin` are tied, so reading from`std::cin` flushes `std::cout`.